# Wrong cell height with autolayout

Tags: ios, swift

I have cell that contain single image view with constraints like that :

```
left - 12 
top - 12
right - 12
height - 300
```

In viewDidLoad i set following:

```
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

However, when table loaded, that cell height is approximately 40 points, and it says in log:

```
Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.
```

In cellForRow.. i set image with url.

Comment: Remove the image height constraint (300) and add a bottom constraint. You want your cell height to be determined dynamically thats why you are using 'UITableViewAutomaticDimension'.

Comment: Yes remove the height constrain and bottom constrain ... it will work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this too.

```
bottom - 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reduce priority constraint ?.. to someone value under that 250... to try if this fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

In constraints you also add bottom constraints as you have posted here your constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The `estimatedRowHeight` cannot be a random value. It needs to be a value that is approximately equal to the expected height. In your case the value mentioned is `80`, but the height of the `imageView` is `300`. So you are getting a warning that the value is ambiguous.

You Change the height of the `tableViewCell` in storyboard to `80` and update the constraints. Set only the trailing, leading, top and bottom constraints. If the height of the image is being used, you can set the value to be `>= 80`.